# Redirect in Reactjs program not working with window.location = 'url';

Tags: reactjs

The application I am working on there is a way to pass a parameter with the URL

`www.myurl.com/?token=xyz`

Which works fine.  The problem is when you have processed the form a button appears on the SPA last page with the following code.

```
<div className="btn-container"><buttonclassName="btn btn-primary btn-sm" onClick={(e) => onCancelClick={(e) => onCancelClick(e)}>Create Another Fo<rm/button></div>
```

The code for the onCancelClick is as follows:

```
        changeNavLinkStatus(true):
        let result = window.location.href.split('?')[0];
        console.log(result); // returning www.myurl.com
        window.location = result;
```

However, the page is redirecting with the `www.myurl.com/?token=xyz` not to `www.myurl.com`.  In other words dropping the queryString.

Can anybody tell me why this is not working?

Comment: Try instead window.location.href = result

Comment: I tried this, but it is still redirecting to www.myurl.com/?token=xyz.  It is not dropping the /?token=xyz.  Puzzling.

Comment: you could use the useNavigate hook and that should drop it. If this doesn't drop it there maybe something on the site re-adding the token. https://reactrouter.com/en/v6.3.0/api#usenavigate